# File upload limit in Nginx & (The server returned a "413 Content Too Large")

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, file-upload, proxy

I made a file upload configuration within a website. The file can be successfully uploaded to the server. But I get this error when the file size increases. In my Nginx configuration files,  `client_max_body_size 100M;` for http and server blocks; I added the line. But I couldn't solve the problem. What do I have to do for this?

[image: Screenshot of the returning error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to edit your `php.ini` which is currently loaded. You can find this from `<?php phpinfo();` then edit the following.

```
memory_limit = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I made these edits. but it did not improve. Then I added the parameters ```max_execution_time = 300``` and ```max_input_time = 300``` But still the same problem persists. Is there anything else you would suggest?

Comment: just making sure, have you restarted php fpm and nginx?

Comment: yes i did them too.

Comment: I solved the problem. I applied the settings you said on ```fpm/php.ini``` and problem solved. Thank you.